# Wordpress: disable sanitize function for input from backend

Tags: wordpress, hyperlink, tags, strip, sanitize

I want to disable sanitize function of Wordpress for input from API, like links and images. Right now, if I post text like ..

```
<a href="">link</a> text link
```

or ..

```
<img src="" /> images
```

Wordpress use sanitize function to strip these tags and show it like text. How can I disable for posts from the backend (wp-admin) for all new posts?

Comment: Is this saving of custom meta boxes or the default editor for posts?

Comment: it is the default posts textarea input field, but I use a custom theme.